# How to create a numeric ruler and evenly spaced numeric width markers

Tags: perl, format, range, printf

I am new to Perl. An exercise, where I am to create a numeric ruler from which, I size columns for data at 20 characters-width, is proving a little difficult to complete. So far, I have,

```
printf “%10d” x 5, (1..6);

@ruler = (1..10) x 7;
Print @ruler, “\n”;
```

It should look something like,

```
1         2         3         4
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

What I get for the top row of numbers is an error, ‘Redundant argument in printf at <script.pl> line #; the bottom row produces numbers from 1 to 10, as it ought with the range operator, but I would like it to produce 1 to 9 with a zero on the end. I did think to start the range from 0, but I haven’t figured out how to remove the first index and only the first index.

I would be grateful for your guidance with both issues.

Comment: @zdim  wiith regard to (2); starting the range from `0..10`, then remove the first index `$_[0]`, so that the range is now `1..10`. None of this makes sensible anyway, because I still would not acheive 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0.

Comment: Alright, I see now what you meant; thanks for clarifying it.  I've removed my comments (to clean up this space) since they're all addressed in ikegami's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided *desired output* starts *count* from `11` instead `1` -- it doesn't look right.

Perhaps OP intended to start count from `1` until some `$max` value with placing a digit representing *tens* above main counter.

Please study following code sample for compliance with your requirements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $max = shift || 45;

rule($max);

sub rule {
    my $max = shift;
    
    my($a,$b);
    $a .= ' ' x 9 . $_ for 1..$max/10;
    $b .= $_ % 10      for 1..$max;
    
    say $a . "\n" . $b;
}
```

Output

```
         1         2         3         4
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
```

Original OP's code requires slight modification to achieve desired output

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $max = shift || 45;

printf "%10d" x int($max/10) . "\n", (1..$max/10);
print  $_ % 10 for 1..$max;
print "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and insight. I have been studying your more elaborate coding. Aspects of it are not completely understood; for instance `$max = shift || 45;` I understand that you remove the element at $_[0], but to what does '45' relate and how exactly is `$max` being used?

Comment: The second of the two solutions is more in line with how I would approach the exercise, given the knowledge gained up to this point. I am, however, unclear as to how you utilise `$max/10`; I would appreciate a little more demystification, if you could. Thank you.

Comment: @Den - `$max = shift || 45;` instructs look for first argument on command line and if it provided then assign it to `$max` other wise assign 45 as value `$max`. `$max` defines maximum value for **rule** -- what maximum value should be on the **rule** (or in physical terms - how long is the **rule**).

Comment: @Den - `$max` defines how long should be the **rule**. Now we need to print _tens_ of the rule without trailing `0` (10,20,30,...). To print only first digit we need to know how many times we must print it and we achieve this by dividing `$max` by 10. For example a default `$max` value equal `45` -- `45/10=4.5`. If we use value of `4.5` as a top of range we get `(1..4)` and print it with format `%10d` [10 positions right adjusted] -- desired spacing for _tens_ achieved.

Comment: @Den - with `my $max = 45;` next line `printf "%10d" x int($max/10) . "\n", (1..$max/10);` will produce following equivalent `print "%10d%10d%10d%10d\n", (1,2,3,4);`.

Comment: @Den - `my $max = shift || 45;` is the simplest way to take an argument from command line. Perl to accept arguments from command line utilizes an array `@ARGV` and you can use `$ARGV[1]` what is equivalent to `shift` -- perl on script start knows that `shift` should be applied to `@ARGV` array. Same method is often used when an arguments passed into subroutine -- you can write `my $val = $_[0]` or `my $val = shift` both are equivalent.

Comment: @Den -- [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift), [range operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators), [printf function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_printf.htm)

Comment: @Den -- try to run `script.pl {rule_length}` for demo, where `{rule_length}` is a maximum digital value on the rule (for example 68).

Comment: @Polar_Bear Thank you for elaborating on your algorithms. Aspects of it (shorthand and shortcuts) are not familiar to me as I am working through a formal introduction to Perl. I shall review it again and try to  implement the code in the various forms you have laid out. As for up-voting; I did up-vote you, but I noticed that the start point for voting was -1; my vote set you at zero, which I did find strange. If I am permitted to vote again, I shall. If the vote is not reflected, I can only apologise and thank you for your help.

Comment: Den - as you just starting with _Perl_ I would suggest to search in Google for `Perl bookshelf`, you will be surprised by result. I must note that these books show theirs's age but still a very good start in perl programming.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is due to the fact that you pass 6 numbers to `printf`, but the format only requires 5.

---

To me,

```
1         2         3         4
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

reads as

```
11, 12, 13, ..., 19, 10, 21, 22, 23, ...
```

Why does it start with 11? Why is 10 between 19 and 21?

The following makes more sense:

```
          1         2         3         4
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890      0-based
```

and

```
         1         2         3         4
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890       1-based
```

---

I'm not going to give the solution outright.

- If you want the numbers 1 to 9 and 0, that would be `1..9, 0`.
- `%10d` will add padding on the left. `%-10d` will add padding on the right.
- Nothing says you can't prefix the output with something that doesn't repeat, like a zero or a space.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I will have a little play with the concepts and solutions you have presented, but I have accepted the answer from Polar bear (not blindly so) because it is close to how I thought about approaching the exercise.

Comment: The reason the scale seems off is because I was frustrated attempting to create the scale an it not being produced and shown correctly at the output; I moved to a different device that enabled me to modify and correct my text, by which time, I was happy to to approximate the idea. I did, however, intimate that the graphic is an approximation. Nonetheless, 5hank you for pointing out that our best work is all in the detail.